# Call facebook api with app access token and retrieve feed from user's page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token

This might sound like a silly question but I don't understand exactly how tokens work.

Context: I have a webapp where a user can press a button and they login with their facebook credentials, giving me permission of 'manage_pages'. The idea of the webapp there will be a cron running each 5 minutes on the server, that will retrieve the posts of the users and show them in the webapp.

Steps:

1. User clicks the button, logins into facebook (so I can have an access token, let's call it **user-access-token**).
2. Webapp makes request '/me/accounts' (using the **user-access-token**),so I can get the Page ID of one of the user's pages.
3. Webapp request to my internal API and stores in the DB the PageID of the user.

Now, I have the mentioned cron that, each 5 minutes, make a request '{page_id}/feed' to get the posts of this page to then show them in my webapp. To do this, I am using the Facebook SDK for PHP and I do:

- Login with my app id and my secret.
- I get an access token (let's call it **my-app-access-token**)
- I do the request '{page_id}/feed', sending **my-app-access-token** but **fails**

  - So, why does it **fail**? I know it is something to do with the access token, because if I use the **user-access-token** I can do the request in the server fine, but if I use **my-app-access-token**, I can not.
  - Why can't I use **my-app-access-token** if the user has given me permission of manage_pages?
  - The alternative I thought of is that, on the step **3**, I can store the **user-access-token** as well. But if I do that, I think that the token will expire after some time, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do the request '{page_id}/feed', sending my-app-access-token but fails

If the page is not public or access restricted in any way, then you can not use the app access token, but need to use a user access token for a user that can see the page, or a page access token.

> [...] But if I do that, I think that the token will expire after some time, right?

Extended page access tokens do not have a default expiry. (They may however expire for other reasons, for example if the page admin users whose token was used to request the page token changes their account password.)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: Thanks. I have been reading a bit. As far as I understood, **long-lived** page token do not expire. So, I should I go for the alternative: when I send the page id to my db, I can store the token (that, in fact, as it will be a short-lived token, I can use my app id + my secret + the page token of the user's page and with that generate a **long-lived** token and store that one that has no expiration time. Am I right?

Comment: You need to extend the short-lived user token first, and then request the page token with the extended user token.